# Word document read speed is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, ms-word, vsto

I read word document with MS Interop lib. But 50 page word document read word by word 30 minute

My code:

```
var app = new ApplicationClass();
object file = filePath;
object nullobject = Missing.Value;

var doc = app.Documents.Open
    (ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);

doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
app.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Maybe this depends on document size and machine performance? Also why don't you call `app.Quit()`?

Comment: What does app.Quit(); do ?

Comment: Have you looked at opening the Word file in-process? The new(ish) Office Open XML format should be easy enough to parse.

Comment: No, word file dnot use aother program.

Comment: parse word document to add database. Program was fast but formated windows, program is slow now.